# Is there a way to have High Contrast mode and Full Screen Zoom enabled simultaneously?

Tags: windows-7, accessibility, contrast, magnifier

My father has vision issues and would like it if the computer screen on his Windows 7 computer could be put in High Contrast mode at the same time as the Full Screen Zoom?

Seems that they are mutually exclusive for some reason, and I don't know why.  He could use colour inversion, but switching between colour inversion and not is not easy and his dexterity isn't the greatest, and sometimes colour inversion is more of a hindrance than a help.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use computer software to realize this.

You can try the software named **whatcolor**.
WhatColor is a freeware that enables users to identify colors by selecting pixels. The program magnifies an area around the cursor from which the user can select some pixels to identify. The program will then tell the user the color of the selected pixel is, along with providing an RGB value for it. WhatColor, however, suffers from some limitations. Given its use in identifying and notifying the color to the user, it can come in handy if color blind users need to refer to colors in a document; or if another document or page refers to specific colors that might otherwise not be clear. Further, it can only be used with Windows 7, 8 and 10. It can be downloaded from here.
http://www.hikarun.com/e/

[image]
   Highly appreciate your Filial piety.
Have a nice day!

Comment: How does this app result in increasing the contrast of objects on the screen while zooming in?